# Spring abstract repository class not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have `CustomerRepository`. When it's just `class` it gets autowired into other classes just fine. When I make it to `abstract class` it gives me an error:

`Field customerRepository in com.xxx.service.CustomerService required a bean of type 'com.xxx.repository.CustomerRepository' that could not be found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why you are getting this error is when you are autowired a class spring will create a bean but in case of abstract object can not be instantiated by spring

Comment: Sad, I don't have any abstract methods defined, so it would be nice, is spring could do it :)

Answer (score 0):

It make sense to define a class as **Abstract class** if its some of the methods or all the methods are abstract(without implementation). and Abstract class can not be instantiated in Java that`s why you need to provide a class which will be extending that particular abstract class.

abstract ClassA(){}

@Component
ClassB extends ClassA{}

so instead of autowiring the ClassA you need to autowire the ClassB

Comment: It also makes sense if you implement JpaRepositor<T, R> and don't want to implement the methods yourself. Then you'd like to make class abstract. And have some of your methods mixed with springs generated methods. :)